# VBA Copy Dynamic Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Sub PrepWork()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("O:\SFS_Data_Repository\CR&G\PCRBA\Rcn_24000646\FIS & 
Profile Filtered Reports\Raw Data FIS_04112018_24000646.xlsx")
Set y = 
Workbooks.Open("O:\SFS_Data_Repository\CR&G\PCRBA\Rcn_24000646\Matching on 
Loaner Computer 6\FIS_AND-VAN-Trxn_lst6_DDA_last4_cardnum_20180411-Filtered-
LCPTR.xlsx")

x.Sheets("Details").Range("A2:BU" & Cells(Rows.Count, 
"BU").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

y.Sheets("FISV").Range("A4").PasteSpecial

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

My data that I am copying always goes from column A to BU, but the number of rows varies.  For some reason, it will only copy and paste in two rows worth of data every time.

Why won't it copy the whole data set and paste?

Comment: I don't know if it is related to your current problem but you are missing references to the workbook and relevant sheet. Try: `x.Sheets("Details").Cells(x.Sheets("Details").Rows.Count, 
"BU").End(xlUp).Row`. You should better assign these sheets to variables and use these variables instead.

Comment: Thanks!  Would I add that piece of code in addition to what I currently have or in replace of?  My copy range starts in Row 2 (A2:BU) and my paste range begins in Row 4 (A4:BU)

Comment: When you code `Cells(Rows.Count, "BU").End(xlUp).Row` it refers to currently active worksheet's row number of last used cell in Column "BU". If you reference `x.Sheets("Details").` before any range object (like Cells, Range, Rows, etc..), it refers to the desired sheet instead of activesheet. So the answer to your question is "In replace of". I hope this is clear for you.

Comment: `A2:BU` range is incomplete. When the code checks the last used cell's row number, it will be completed. Suppose that your last row is `200` in Column "BU". Then it will be interpreted like `x.Sheets("Details").Range("A2:BU200").Copy`. I believe it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

VBA Uses `ActiveSheet` in front of `Range()` and `Cells()` objects if they are not specified.

Secondary, there is no need to use the clipboard. If you want to copy values, use direct assignment. Expand a range into multiple cells with the `.Resize()` function.

Try the following:

```
Sub PrepWork()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("O:\SFS_Data_Repository\CR&G\PCRBA\Rcn_24000646\FIS Profile Filtered Reports\Raw Data FIS_04112018_24000646.xlsx")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("O:\SFS_Data_Repository\CR&G\PCRBA\Rcn_24000646\Matching on Loaner Computer 6\FIS_AND-VAN-Trxn_lst6_DDA_last4_cardnum_20180411-Filtered-LCPTR.xlsx ")

    Dim n As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = x.Sheets("Details").Range("BU2")
    ' Start form BU2 and count down the rows
    n = x.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    ' Take n rows and 73 columns from 'A2' in x and copy the
    ' values into n rows and 72 columns under "A4" in y
    y.Sheets("FISV").Range("A4").Resize(n, 73).Value = _
        x.Sheets("Details").Range("A2").Resize(n, 72).Value

    'Close x:
    x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I again get a "subscript out of range" error on the line: set r = x.sheets("Details").Range("BU2")

Comment: Without seeing the actual data, I have no way of known if the code is correct. The method is valid (Setting a range object from `Sheets().Range()`) and the copy is valid. It is your job to make it work with the data you have (starting cells, number of rows & column, destination range, .. )

Comment: The data I am copying starts in Cell A2 and goes to Column BU and probably around 250K rows.... I'm not sure why I am getting an error... but thank you for your help, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you replace

```
x.Sheets("Details").Range("A2:BU" & Cells(Rows.Count, "BU").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
```

with the following:

```
With x.Sheets("Details")
    .Range("A2:BU" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BU").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
end With
```

Which is basically what Tehscript mentions above.

Comment: I get a "subscript out of range" error on that line of code

Comment: have you taken into account my edit? I was a bit hasty at posting it.

Comment: @ZacharyDesgain which shows that your unqualified use of `Cells()` is what's tripping you up! `Cells` refers to the _currently active_ worksheet. which one is currently active when this is running? If you use `.Cells().Copy` then you're specifying which sheet you want to copy from. Think through your code to make sure you're referencing the right sheet.

Comment: which is exactly what ja72's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818137/2344413) fixes

Comment: @FreeMan I'm still a novice to VBA code: don't have to get all snippy when I am trying to get some help

Comment: @ZacharyDesgain - my bad - that wasn't intended to be snippy, it was intended to get you to think about what you're writing. It took me a while to learn not to use unqualified `Range()` and `Cells()`. Mostly it was asking about bugs like this that got it through my skull to stop doing that.

Comment: @ZacharyDesgain is your worksheet name correct? does your workbook have a sheet with this exact name?

Comment: @JeroenLangenaken Yes I tried your edit and got the error I mentioned... The workbook/worksheet names are correct because my initial code was copying and pasting data, but only two rows of it, not the whole data set

Comment: I get the "subscript out of range" error.. I dont know why